# Only MM part of MM//DD/YYYY is assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was learning how to work with React Router by using Open Weather Map API. The problem I faced is that I wanted to create dynamic routing by passing date in format of **MM//DD/YYYY** and then access it like this const `chosenDay = props.match.params.date` the problem is chosenDay is equalized to **"09"**, that is, instead of being equal to, for example, **"09/20/2019"** `chosenDay` is equal to **"09"** only. Guys, if you need more details please let me know I just did not want to confuse you with truckload of code. Thank you.

Comment: As you have noticed, it parses it based on `\\` in the url. Ideally, you would be using a route that doesn't have those characters. Is it possible to just use dashes instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve using three following ways

1. Encode the value as it has slash `/`
2. Pass it as query param instead path param
3. Define the router path to get three different path variables like following.

   `<Route path='/foo/:day/:month/:year' component={YourPage} />`